# I can't download remastersys

Tags: remastersys

I want to creat a remaster with remastersys,I have remastersys 3.0.3.
I created the iso file with that but it don't accept my user&pass,user=custom,pass=blank
Now I want to use remastersys 3.0.4 or above.
Remastersys repository is shut in my country.
Please help me and send me remastersys file or upload it for me and my countrymans.
Thanks

yaser.amiri95@gmail.com

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can change your reps from `/etc/apt/sources.list`. change `http://ir.archi...` to something else like `http://de.archi...`. Then `sudo apt-get update` :)

You can use use `apt-get` with `proxyfier`

PS: CloneZilla might be a better option. 
PPS: Remastersys is no longer supported, actually-. There is a new project, `Relinux`, that aims to be better than Remastersys ever was, while allowing you to do the same thing (remaster your system). See this blog for full details: https://relinuxkit.wordpress.com/

Comment: I used the relinux but iso has an error